# Is it appropriate to attach a store listener to a sub component in React Flux?

Tags: reactjs, flux

I have a component named "Flight booking" and a sub component named "Map" inside of it. I also have a store named "MapStore" with its actions. Can I attach the store to the sub component or I have to attach it to the top component to fit to the flux architecture?

Answer (score 2):

Flux architecture says that you should have 2 kinds of components;

1. Containers:  Receive no props from parent components, but are connected to stores.
2. Components:  Receive props from parent components, but are not connected to stores.

This distinction is meant to help readability and make the code easier to maintain.  It's generally a good idea to follow it.

For your specific usecase, though, you could have your Map component as either type.  You just need to be consistent with how you handle your data.  You should either;

1. Make `Map` a Container.  Any values it needs should be stored within flux, rather than passed as props (this likely means rewriting some of your `FlightBooking` methods to save values to flux, rather than to it's internal state).
2. Make `Map` a Component.  `FlightBooking` will be responsibe for getting any values it needs from the stores and passing them as props.

Regarding the comment made by Drew;  It is true that the second approach I listed will cause FlightBooking to re-run it's `render` method.  But you really shouldn't worry too much about that.  React is designed to handle those updates efficiently, and will not actually rerender the DOM unless it detects changes in the virtual-dom.  The performance impact here is incredibly minimal.

Comment: It means that a container can be included into a normal component in the DOM hierarchy if I follow the first solution?
For example, 
<FlightBooking>
  <Map></Map>
</FlightBooking>

Answer (score 1):

Attaching sub components to a store is an appropriate strategy. It's quite common in redux, and actually has some performance benefits. For example if you attached your top component to `MapStore` react would have to rerender the entire app on every change. React makes this relatively efficient, but if only a subset of your app cares about `MapStore` then it's more efficient to only try to rerender that subset in the first place.